# Transform depending on time (Unity & C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my gameObject to transform 0.5 units on x-axis every 0.5 seconds, I've created coroutine for these, check the script, what is the problem?

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float Speed;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
    StartCoroutine(Movement());
}
IEnumerator Movement()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it only does it once? You need to have a loop in your coroutine...

Comment: Thanks. That's it.

Comment: Can you tell me what was the problem before?

Comment: The problem is that your coroutine returns at some point ending the routine, `StartCoroutine` doesn't loop it for you, you need to do that yourself. That is so you can create coroutines that are short lived, or continue forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a loop. If you want an endless loop, you can use "while(true)" or "for(;;)"

Example

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float Speed;
int k;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    StartCoroutine(Movement());

}
IEnumerator Movement()
{
    for (k = 1; k <= 100; k++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```